# WooCommerce Color Variants

Tags: woocommerce, e-commerce, product, variants

On WooCommerce, if we have multiple colors of the a given shirt and would like to show different Product Name, Product Description, Product Quantity, Product Price and set of pictures for each color of the product(i.e. 5 pics of red shirt on the red product page, not one red, one green, one blue), is there a way to do so? Presumably should create the products as two separate products and have a way to link them to one another such that the color options show up on the different pages, but the user is routed to a new page when clicking on the color option.

Is there a plug-in for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create seperate products, as in WooCommerce you can define "attributes" (also called variants) for each of your products, you can create an attribute "color", create several color values and on the product edit page, link some of them to you products, you can define a different price, upload new product picture (etc.) to each of the variants.

For more please visit:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: Thanks Chris, but the issue is that we can't change the Product Name: like Red Cotton Shirt, Blue Cotton Shirt. Additionally, you can't change the related product / "You May Also Love products" associated with each product color with WooCommerce. Other sites seem to do this by creating two separate product pages -- and then creating a two-way linkage between them. See here as one example:  https://bbdakota.com/collections/dresses/products/samantha-ruffle-dress-sugar-coral